Sideways table and caption rotation in between text without creating new page
I would like to have a referenceable table in my appendix/section where the appendix title is at the top, followed by a small explanatory text and both (normal/upright orientation) followed by a rotated table where the table caption is at the top and also rotated. All should be on the same page.
I have tried several methods such as sidewaystable, rotatebox (both with and without using minipages or varwidth).
This question: Sideways table takes new page has not been answered in my eyes and the link to this answer: Rotate table with caption on the same page only shows how to rotate the caption for/with the table but does not solve the new page problem.
The answer to this question: Place two sideway Tables next to each other on one side also creates a page for the table which i want to prevent.
I also tested different placing and forcing options but nothing works (with my limited tex-abilities..).
Here is some small example: (I have to use this documentclass)
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,parskip=half,headsepline,footsepline,headings=small,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
Some explanatory text for \ref{tab:ref}. 
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption[Table content]{Table caption on the top}\label{tab:ref}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Some & random& table & entries \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}


Is anyone out there who can help me? Thanks a lot!

I know this is not perfect, but it will works per your requirement:
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,parskip=half,headsepline,footsepline,headings=small,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
Some explanatory text for \ref{tab:ref}. 

\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{minipage}{25pc}
\captionof{table}[Short Title]{Table caption on the top\label{tab:ref}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Some & random& table & entries \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
%\end{table}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot for your fast answer!
I noticed, that the small example that I gave you did not reflect the whole problem I was having, but based on your answer I was able to solve it.
I would like to share my (also not perfect) solution with an extended example:
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,parskip=half,headsepline,footsepline,headings=small,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
Some explanatory text for \ref{tab:ref}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{center}

\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textheight}
\centering
\parbox{14cm}{
\captionof{table}[Short Title]{Table caption on the top with more text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\label{tab:ref}}
}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\height}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
First & Second & Third & Fourth\\
\\
1. & First long random entry & and more and more & and more and more. \\
2. & Second column entry & and more and more & and more and more.\\
3. & Third column entry & and more and more & and more and more.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}%
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}


I hope this can help someone in the future.
